# Python not working to draw a hexagon using PIL and aggdraw

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, generator, draw, aggdraw

My code is as follows, but it does not work out as expected to draw a hexagon, with no hexagon and error either.

```
import math
from PIL import Image
from aggdraw import Draw, Brush, Pen


def hexagon_generator(edge_length, offset):
    """Generator for coordinates in a hexagon."""
    x, y = offset
    for angle in range(0, 360, 60):
        x += math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * edge_length
        y += math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * edge_length
        yield int(x)
        yield int(y)


def main():
    image = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), 'white')
    draw = Draw(image)
    hexagon = hexagon_generator(40, offset=(30, 15))
    print(list(hexagon))
    draw.polygon(list(hexagon), Pen('black'), Brush('red'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hexagon_generator` creates a generator - the elements of `hexagon`  can only be iterated through once, after which it is "exhausted". When you call `print(list(hexagon))` this takes all elements from the iterator you created in the previous line, and thus when you write `list(hexagon)` again in the next line, this creates an empty list.

Cast it directly to a list to solve this issue (not printing it would work too):

```
def main():
    image = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), 'white')
    draw = Draw(image)
    hexagon = list(hexagon_generator(40, offset=(30, 15)))
    print(hexagon)
    draw.polygon(hexagon, Pen('black'), Brush('red'))
```